# How to get the value of a selected radio button when the id for them is dynamically generated?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dynamic, radio-button

My Html looks like below:

```
<div id="associatedAPListTable" style="float:left"><Associated (Destination)>
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="listContainer" align="center" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th class="tableheader" align="left" width="170">MAC address</th>
            <th class="tableheader" align="left" width="170">LradName</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="associated_tablebody">
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
```

My javascript looks like below:

```
function getAssociatedList(){
var associatedAPListArray=[];
var xhrArgs = {
    url:"abc/sample/resource",
    preventCache: true,
    contentType: "application/json"
};
var deferred = dojo.xhrGet(xhrArgs);
deferred.addCallback(function(response){
    var associatedApListObj = dojo.fromJson(response);
    var firstJsonObject;
    var row = '';
    for (i=0; i <= dojo.fromJson(associatedApListObj.items).length-1; i++){
        firstJsonObject = dojo.fromJson(associatedApListObj.items)[i];
        var MacAddress = firstJsonObject.MacAddress;
        var LradName=firstJsonObject.LradName;
        var style_td='<td align="left" width="170">';
        row+='<tr>'+style_td+'<input type="radio"'+'id="associated_'+i+'" name="associatedAp"/ >'+MacAddress+'</td>'+style_td+LradName+'</td></tr>';
    }
    document.getElementById('associated_tablebody').innerHTML = row;
    });
}
```

So, now that I have created and displayed these radio buttons, 
I need to get the value of the radio button selected. Could someone please tell me how to do this is Javascript and not jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the `id` of the checked radio button:

```
document.querySelector('input[type=radio]:checked').getAttribute('id');
```

Comment: This is getting the id of the parent . That is, I have a parent input radio button, onclick of it, it calls the above method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to listen to user events, you need to add an event listener to the elements after creating them.

```
function handleChange(e) {
  // is it checked?
  console.log(this.checked)
  // what's the value?
  console.log(this.value)
}

var inputs = document.getElementById('associated_tablebody').querySelectorAll('input')

inputs.forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('change', handleChange)
})
```

---

Update

I thought you wanted to listen for events on each input. My bad.

If you're just looking to find the single radio button that's selected after you add the html to the page, just filter your result to the selected element and store (or log) it's value:

```
var inputs = document.getElementById('associated_tablebody').querySelectorAll('input')

var selected = [].slice.call(inputs).filter(function(el) {
  return el.checked
}).pop()

console.log(selected.value)
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jw7e0aL4/8/

Comment: This is working great. But the problem is, onclick of one radio, the console displays once. 

Onclick of another radio, the console displays twice. 
Therefore the count keeps increasing according to the number of times I click.

Comment: Is there a way to print the console just once on click of one radio button? 
It looks like it is looping

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm guessing you want the Mac Address of the selected radio button?

Based on your code it's unclear because you say

> I need to get the value of the radio button selected

Yet, this input tag you are generating

`<input type="radio"'+'id="associated_'+i+'" name="associatedAp"/ >`

has no value set else it might look like this:

`<input type="radio"'+'id="associated_'+i+'" name="associatedAp" value="'+MacAddress+'"/ >`

To be clear the entire line of code would look like:

`row+='<tr>'+style_td+'<input type="radio"'+'id="associated_'+i+'" name="associatedAp" value="'+MacAddress+'" />'+MacAddress+'</td>'+style_td+LradName+'</td></tr>';`

Now you need to be able to select it and get the value:

`var selection = document.querySelector('input:checked').value;`

Comment: Thanks @Levi. But this is returning "on" and not the value of the selected radio.

Comment: "on" is being returned by default because it is selected, but has no value set, so that's good in the sense that your code `var selection = document.querySelector('input:checked').value;` is working.  However, you need to set a 'value' attribute within your radio input tag, and once you do so you will get back the value you actually want.